# SlidingMenuExample error, cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

I try to learn how to use the existing code in my eclipse, so far ActionBarSheclock has success but SlidingMenu keep showing same error and I couldn't solve it
I downloaded the code from [here](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)
and follow the instruction from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKKIlFZkOeM)
but my result is like this

left_and_right cannot be resolved or is not a field

content_frame cannot be resolved or is not a field

attach cannot be resolved or is not a field

shadow_width cannot be resolved or is not a field

slidingmenu_offset cannot be resolved or is not a field

and many more....
Can anyone pointed out where I did wrong and help me resolve these error?

Comment: show some code,where you struck.

Comment: my reputation are too low couldn't share picture, if show code will over the characters limit.. I only can tell that every single .java file in /src hving same error

Answer (score 0):

it will be much easy to add Slide menu form activity class

do like this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTitle(R.string.attach);
    // set the content view
    setContentView(R.layout.content);
    // configure the SlidingMenu
    SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.YOUR_MENU_LAYOUR);
}
```

i Hope it help any question you can ask me i'll be here

Comment: erm.. accurately I still don't understand how the slide menu work, that why I try to learn the structure from the code example..
Thanks for try to help me up but I just don't understand how to use the code you hv provide

Comment: it is a library,you check out all the source code and learn by your self.

Comment: so I should create this and save it as a JAR file rite?